# Audio applications (spotify etc) continue playing when bluetooth calls come in

Tags: applications, bluetooth, audio, samsung-galaxy-s-5, bluetooth-audio

When I'm in my car and listening to the ESPN Radio app, the Spotify app, or the Soundcloud app, and I receive a call either on my bluetooth or the d/c phone itself, the audio application keeps playing the podcast or music over top the call. This only happens some of the time, sometimes it pauses as it should.

Also, this may be related. If I get in the car after using spotify on headphones, it will start playing on the bluetooth even if I had paused and closed the app long before. I'm not sure if it's related, but it's more strange bluetooth issues.

My phone is a completely up to date Samsung Galaxy S5 with no alterations like being jailbroken or anything. Just a base model S5. My carrier is ATT.

Comment: Have you ever tried to reset your phone?